# Annual Effective Rate Compounded Quarterly

Tags: finance

Confused with this question especially with what to do with the "expense charge"? Can anyone help?

A fund earns interest at the nominal rate of 8% compounded quarterly. At
the end of each quarter, just after interest is credited, an expense charge
equal to 0.4% of the fund is withdrawn. Determine the annual effective
rate realized by the fund.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After $1$ quarter, an initial unit of money, after deduction of "expense charge"  becomes $ 1.02\times\frac{99.6}{100}$

Raising the above to a power of $4$ yields a figure of $\approx 1.0652$

Thus the effective annual interest rate $\approx 6.52\%$